# How can I set QTreeView's current index to a specific value in PyQt6 or PySide6?

Tags: python, pyside6, pyqt6

i use this offical example https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_widgets_itemviews_jsonmodel.html
then i want to make vaule be clicked in QTreeView by a specific value。like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXDis.png)

maybe it means update treeView's currentIndex

i tried this way ,but QModelIndex can not be updated

`index = QModelIndex(3,3,QModelIndex()) view.setCurrentIndex(index)`

sorry , my English is not good

Comment: Hey, could you make a reproducible example to help other people answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example